# ObjectiveC constant in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an objective C constant file XMPPConstant.h(only no .m file) in swift that has some variable. How to use that constant in the swift file.?

Content of XMPPConstant.h is :

```
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h> 
static NSString * const  kServerDomainName    =    @"TestDomain";
```

Comment: `#import` the header file in the bridging header file.

Comment: that file is imported.

Comment: is there show any error like file not found?

Comment: There is no .m file

Comment: No such variable found is the error I am getting.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem – if that "XMPPConstant.h" is imported from the bridging header file then `kServerDomainName` is visible in Swift.

Comment: It works for me with Xcode 8 and Xcode 9.

Comment: You have to import `XMPPConstant.h` into bridging header file